# PDFSharp image being scaled

Tags: pdf, graphics

I have an image element that I am writing using PdfSharp. The ActionScript for it is below:

```
<<
  /BitsPerComponent 8
  /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
  /Filter /FlateDecode
  /Height 122
  /Intent /Perceptual
  /Interpolate true
  /Length 1325
  /Subtype /Image
  /Type /XObject
  /Width 121
>>
```

The problem is that this image is being written as a very small scaled vector. Is there anything wrong with this attribute that would cause the image to be tiny?

Comment: C#, .Net - nothing, that I can see in your question has anything to do with either - other than mentioning PDFSharp.

Comment: This question ended up being a lot less C# specific than I thought, edited.